# Cannot get Repeat control to break out multi-value field

Tags: xpages

What I am trying to do *should* be very simple.  I have a multi-value text field called activityLog.   The field is set via a java method when various things happen.  If I look at the backend data, it clearly is a multivalue field.

I went through the steps in Dave Leedy's Notes-in-9 #14, as well as tried to follow Tommy Valand's blog post here --> http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2011/03/repeat-controls-and-multivalue-fields.html.  Neither seems to work for me.  The result is that they list contents that are concatenated together in both cases.

The values ARE returned as a VECTOR.  I can verify this by getting the size(), and by isolating specific elements using elementAt().   I was about to just make a for loop to get around this, but I want to know *why* it is failing.  Repeats always seem to give me trouble.  I was also want to leave straight forward code for me or future developers.  There is probably something easy that I am missing.

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="rowData">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValue("activityLog")}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField14" value="#{javascript:rowData}">
    </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
```

UPDATE:  The Repeat control is reading the Vector, but is NOT adding a new line automatically after each iteration.  Trying to add a new line manually is not working, having tried JS "/n" & "/r" and @NewLine()

Comment: A newline character wouldn't show up in HTML (except perhaps inside a `<pre><code/></pre>`)... add a `<br />` after your `<xp:text />`.

Comment: Tim, thats was it.  I had a feeling it would be something simple.  Thanks so much.  If you put this in an answer, I will go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers ignore whitespace except inside tags specifically intended to display whitespace. Add a break tag (`<br />`) or component (`<xp:br />`) inside the repeat, and the browser will display a new line for each iteration of the repeat.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `<br/>` or `<xp:br />` suggested by Tim is an effective approach. But consider fixing the issue in the `<xp:text/ >` element instead.

The `<xp:text />`element creates a `<span />` in the output HTML by default. Spans are, by default, displayed inline meaning that they do not have a line feed ahead of them. But you can add a CSS rule to the element which makes it a block element instead of inline. Add this CSS using a style tag: `<xp:text style="display:block;" />`or in a CSS class that include the rule `{display: block}`

A final way is to tell the the page to render a `<div />` tag instead of a `<span />` tag. DIVs are, by default, block elements. Do this with: `<xp:text tagName="div"/>`. (however, be careful because the default behavior of both DIVs and SPANs can be changed).

Comment: Thanks Newbs!  This is good info here that I am bet will help me and others down the line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of breaking out a multivalue fields, you only missed one thing. Accessing each row, I've added the rowColl variable indexVar="rowColl" and so you access it rowData[rowColl]

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="rowData" indexVar="rowColl">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValue("activityLog")}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField14" value="#{javascript:rowData[rowColl]}">
    </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: I actually tried using the index earlier with no luck.   This time, when I change the code to yours, I get no output.  But, when I write to the console using print(rowColl) and print(rowData), then it prints  the correct values.  I am baffled, there is no rendered code or anything else unusual with the computerField.  Any ideas?

Comment: Fredrik, here is more info.  The repeat doesn't create a new line for each entry.  After removing the index (rowColl), it does display and adding " -- " to the return value, it does add the text between each entry.   The problem is that the repeat is not adding a new line.  I am using 9.0.0.  @NewLine() is ignored.